# Android resource linking failed - no syntax error found in xml

Tags: android

In the android studio, I have this error: **Android resource linking failed**.

According to other posts, the error is in the xml file. Then, I opened all xml files one by one. However, I didn't find any syntax error in xml.

Also, I run the **Analyze-->Inspect code-->OK**. But it only shows warnings, no error. Is there any other ways to locate the error, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error once. In my case I had duplicate lines in one of the XML files,

something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

After removing the duplicate line of code the error was solved.

So check all the resource files that are accessed in your **main_activity**.